# py-faster-rcnn network detection runs on CPU through ROS callback function

Tags: ros, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm trying to test my trained [py-faster-rcnn network](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) for object detection through ROS. I have a node running with many similarities to [demo.py](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/tools/demo.py). Included in the class are commands to execute the network detection on the GPU (given below), however, looking at recall times (~26s) and the system profiler it's fairly clear that the network is running on the CPU. Is there a way to get around this?

```
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
caffe.set_device(0)
cfg.GPU_ID = 0
```

Interestingly, if I run [demo.py](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/tools/demo.py) normally (not through ROS), it executes on the GPU in ~2s

**UPDATE**: after some more detective work, it appears that it is an issue with calling CNN detection within a callback function. Any suggestions? (Other people seem to be experiencing a similar problem - [Callback with GPU processing](http://answers.ros.org/question/239333/callback-with-gpu-processing/))

Thanks,
Will

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240998/py-faster-rcnn-network-detection-runs-on-cpu-through-ros-callback-function/) by [WillAndrew](https://answers.ros.org/users/22907/willandrew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-08-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-03**:
I don't know anything about caffe, but I do know that rospy runs callbacks in a separate thread from the main loop. Perhaps that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved the issue by having the callback function change a global variable which is checked by the main loop/thread as follows:

```
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    if run_test_img == True:
        testImg()
    rate.sleep()
```

A bit hacky but it does the job.

---

Originally posted by [WillAndrew](https://answers.ros.org/users/22907/willandrew/) with karma: 20 on 2016-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2016-09-19**:
Hi Will. I am also trying to implement faster-rcnn inside the ROS framework. I want to run the demo as a ROS node and pass images on ROS topic. I know how to pass images over a ROS topic but was wondering if there are any dependancy issues when I try to integrate faster rcnn within ROS?